# Random sampling simulation in python

Tags: python, random, simulation, sampling

Problem: Assume we have a list of members' IDs: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,....]
I need to run 1000 simulations drawing teams of size 4 at random from all members without replacement. (drawn uniformly at random without replacement from all members)

Output: The final result should be 1000 teams with size of 4.

Thanks

Comment: A homework description without any self written code

Comment: As described, you don't have a fixed population. You need to replace the ... with a concrete upper bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`random.sample(population, k)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.sample):

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence or set. Used for random sampling without replacement.

```
>>> import random
>>> players = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> teams = [random.sample(players, 4) for _ in range(1000)]
>>> teams[0]
[8, 4, 5, 10]
```